# How to adjust the space between references?

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I want to change the space between the references.
[image]

I think maybe change this place, But Idk how to change it.

```py
\if@appendbibformat
    \AtEndPreamble{%
        \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}%
            {%
                \if@authordateformat
                    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
                        bibliography = {References}}
                \else
                    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
                        references = {Bibliography}}
                \fi
                \renewcommand{\bibsetup}{%
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{\tf@topsecname}{\bibname}
                    \vspace{\dimexpr -2\tf@singlelineskip +1\baselineskip \relax}%
                    \singlespacing%
                    \def\tf@adjaftersec{\dimexpr \tf@singlelineskip -\p@ \relax}}
                \renewcommand{\bibitemsep}{1\baselineskip}
                \renewcommand{\bibhang}{0.5in}
            }{}}
\fi
```

---

This is the whole code, I think

```py
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{turabian-formatting}[2018/08/01 Turabian Formatting]

\newif\if@optraggedright\@optraggedrightfalse

\newif\if@authordateformat\@authordateformatfalse

\newif\if@appendbibformat\@appendbibformattrue

\newif\if@endnotesformat\@endnotesformatfalse


% Package options: handling

\DeclareOption{raggedright}{\@optraggedrighttrue}

\DeclareOption{authordate}{\@authordateformattrue}

\DeclareOption{noadjustbib}{\@appendbibformatfalse}

\DeclareOption{endnotes}{\@endnotesformattrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax


\RequirePackage{etoolbox}


% Margin size: 1 inch on all sides
\setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr \paperwidth -2in \relax}
\setlength\hoffset{\z@}

\setlength\textheight{\dimexpr \paperheight -2in \relax}
\setlength\voffset{\z@}

\setlength\oddsidemargin{\z@}
\setlength\evensidemargin{\z@}

% Header top and footer baseline: set to 0.5in from page edges
\setlength\topmargin{-0.5in}
\setlength\headheight{\dimexpr \f@size pt \relax}
\setlength\headsep{\dimexpr 0.5in -\headheight \relax}

\setlength\footskip{0.5in}

% Text spacing is double spaced
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1}
% \setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.5ex}

% Preserve normalsize and footnotesize single spacing baselineskip values

\newlength\tf@singlelineskip
\newlength\tf@fnsinglelineskip

\ifcase \@ptsize
    \setlength\tf@singlelineskip{12pt}
    \setlength\tf@fnsinglelineskip{9.5pt}
\or
    \setlength\tf@singlelineskip{13.6pt}
    \setlength\tf@fnsinglelineskip{11pt}
\or
    \setlength\tf@singlelineskip{14.5pt}
    \setlength\tf@fnsinglelineskip{12pt}
\fi


% Paragraph indent
\setlength\parindent{0.5in}

% Renew \raggedright to preserve paragraph indent and set \@optraggedright to true
\def\raggedright{%
    \let\\\@centercr\@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip
    \leftskip\z@skip
    \@optraggedrighttrue}

% Use \raggedright if raggedright option true
\if@optraggedright \raggedright \fi

% Prevent widowed text with 2 line default
\PassOptionsToPackage{defaultlines=2, all}{nowidow}
\AtEndPreamble{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{nowidow}%
        {}%
        {\RequirePackage{nowidow}}}


% Footnotes: layout and formatting

\PassOptionsToPackage{bottom, marginal}{footmisc}
\if@endnotesformat
    \PassOptionsToPackage{perpage}{footmisc}
\fi

\RequirePackage{footmisc}

\setlength\footnotemargin{\parindent}

% Footnotes: Chicago symbols used when needed
\setfnsymbol{chicago}

% Footnotes: separation between footnotes based on text size
\ifcase \@ptsize
    \setlength\footnotesep{12pt}
\or
    \setlength\footnotesep{18.7pt}
\or
    \setlength\footnotesep{20.4pt}
\fi

\setlength{\skip\footins}{\footnotesep}

% Footnotes: readjust footnote rule size and placement
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
    \vspace*{-3pt}
    \hrule width 2in height 0.4pt
    \vspace*{-4pt}}

% Footnotes: make command to set footnote punctuation
\newcommand{\tf@setfnpunct}[1]{\def\tf@thefnpunct{#1\,\,}}
\tf@setfnpunct{.}

% Footnotes: renew command for typesetting footnotes
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
    \if@optraggedright \raggedright \fi
    \setlength\parindent{\footnotemargin}%
    \setlength\tf@singlelineskip{\tf@fnsinglelineskip}%
    \@thefnmark\tf@thefnpunct#1}


% Page style (headings): place page number in header, top right
\def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
    \let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}
    \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
    \let\markboth\@mkboth
    \let\chaptermark\@gobble
    \let\sectionmark\@gobble}

% Page style (myheadings): make same as headings page style 
\let\ps@myheadings\ps@headings

% Page style (headings): set default page style and page numbering
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% Page style (empty): adjust if twoside option used
\if@twoside
    \def\cleardoublepage{%
        \clearpage
        \ifodd \c@page \else
            \hbox{}
            \thispagestyle{empty}
            \newpage
        \fi}
\fi


% Set top section command name to "section" (default)
\def\tf@topsecname{section}

% Set adjustment for baselineskip after \section and \section* headings
\def\tf@adjaftersec{\dimexpr \baselineskip -\tf@singlelineskip -\p@ \relax}

% Headings formatting: \section, \subsection, and \subsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
    \@startsection{section}{1}%
        {\z@}%
        {-\tf@singlelineskip}%
        {\tf@singlelineskip}%
        {\normalfont\bfseries\normalsize\singlespacing\centering}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
    \@startsection{subsection}{2}%
        {\z@}%
        {-\tf@singlelineskip}%
        {\tf@singlelineskip}%
        {\normalfont\mdseries\normalsize\singlespacing\centering}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
    \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
        {\z@}%
        {-\tf@singlelineskip}%
        {\tf@singlelineskip}%
        {\normalfont\bfseries\normalsize\singlespacing\raggedright}}

% Headings formatting: following paragraphs start with an indent
\def\tf@afterindent{\@afterindenttrue}


% Table of Contents: renew formatting

\def\tf@tocpagestyle{\@empty}

\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \tf@tocpagestyle
    \expandafter\csname \tf@topsecname\endcsname*{\contentsname}%
    \@mkboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}%
    \if@optraggedright
        \let\tf@tocrmarg\@tocrmarg
        \def\@tocrmarg{\tf@tocrmarg plus1fil}
    \fi
    {   \vspace{\dimexpr -3\tf@singlelineskip +1\baselineskip \relax}%
        \singlespacing
        \@starttoc{toc}}}%


% List of Figures and List of Tables: adjust titles

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}

\AtEndPreamble{
    \@ifpackageloaded{polyglosia}%
        {%
            \addto\captionsenglish{%
                \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}
                \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}}%
        }{}
    \@ifpackageloaded{babel}%
        {%
            \addto\captionsenglish{%
                \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}
                \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}}%
        }{}}

% List of Figures
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
    \expandafter\csname \tf@topsecname\endcsname*{\listfigurename}%
    \@mkboth{\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{\tf@topsecname}{\listfigurename}%
    {   \vspace{\dimexpr -3\tf@singlelineskip +1\baselineskip \relax}%
        \singlespacing
        \@starttoc{lof}}}

% List of Tables
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{%
    \expandafter\csname \tf@topsecname\endcsname*{\listtablename}%
    \@mkboth{\listtablename}{\listtablename}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{\tf@topsecname}{\listtablename}%
    {   \vspace{\dimexpr -3\tf@singlelineskip +1\baselineskip \relax}%
        \singlespacing
        \@starttoc{lot}}}

% List of Illustrations
\newcommand{\listillustrationname}{Illustrations}
\def\tf@illustrsection{\normalfont\bfseries\normalsize\singlespacing\noindent}

\newcommand{\listofillustrations}{%
    \expandafter\csname \tf@topsecname\endcsname*{\listillustrationname}%
    \@mkboth{\listillustrationname}{\listillustrationname}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{\tf@topsecname}{\listillustrationname}%
    {   \vspace{\dimexpr -3\tf@singlelineskip +1\baselineskip \relax}%
        \singlespacing
        {\tf@illustrsection Figures}\par\nopagebreak
        \@starttoc{lof}
        \vspace{\tf@singlelineskip}
        {\tf@illustrsection Tables}\par\nopagebreak
        \@starttoc{lot}}}


% Figures and Tables: float positioning

\setlength\textfloatsep{%
    \dimexpr 2\tf@singlelineskip +\p@ \relax minus 1\tf@singlelineskip}
\setlength\floatsep{%
    \dimexpr 1\tf@singlelineskip +\p@ \relax plus 1\tf@singlelineskip}
\setlength\intextsep{%
    \dimexpr 1\tf@singlelineskip +\p@ \relax plus 1\tf@singlelineskip}

\def\fps@table{!htb}
\def\fps@figure{!htb}

% Figures and Tables: caption formatting

\setlength\abovecaptionskip{\z@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{\z@}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
    \vskip\abovecaptionskip
    \if@optraggedright \raggedright \fi
    \small#1. #2\par
    \vskip\belowcaptionskip}


% Lists: enumerate and itemize formatting
\setlength\leftmargini{1.5\parindent}
\setlength\leftmargin{\leftmargini}
\setlength\leftmarginii{\parindent}
\setlength\leftmarginiii{\parindent}
\setlength\leftmarginiv{\parindent}
\setlength\labelsep{.65em}
\setlength\labelwidth{\dimexpr \parindent -\labelsep \relax}

% Lists: formatting command for both enumerate and itemize
\def\tf@listformat{%
    \setlength\topsep{\z@}
    \setlength\itemsep{\z@}
    \setlength\parsep{\z@}
    \setlength\listparindent{\parindent}}

% Lists (enumerate): format of enumerate list labels
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{(\arabic{enumiii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{(\alph{enumiv})}

% Lists (enumerate): redefine enumerate to include formatting command hook
\def\tf@enumerateformat{\tf@listformat}
\def\enumerate{%
    \ifnum \@enumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep \else
        \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
        \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
        \expandafter
        \list
            \csname label\@enumctr\endcsname
            {\usecounter\@enumctr%
            \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
            \tf@enumerateformat}%
    \fi}

% Lists (itemize): redefine itemize to include formatting command hook
\def\tf@itemizeformat{\tf@listformat}
\def\itemize{%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep \else
        \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
        \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
        \expandafter
        \list
            \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
            {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
            \tf@itemizeformat}%
    \fi}


% Block quotation: formatting
\renewenvironment{quotation}
    {%
        \list{}{%
            \setlength\listparindent{\parindent}
            \setlength\itemindent{\listparindent}
            \setlength\leftmargin{\parindent}
            % Adjust right margin based on raggedright option
            \if@optraggedright
                \setlength\rightmargin{\z@}
            \else
                \setlength\rightmargin{\leftmargin}
            \fi
            \setlength\parsep{\z@}
            \setlength\topsep{\dimexpr 2\tf@singlelineskip -\baselineskip \relax}}%
        \singlespacing%
        \item\relax%
    }
    {\endlist}
\def\quote{\quotation}


% thebibliography environment: formatting (adjust \@openbib@code hook default)


\setlength\bibindent{\parindent}

\newlength{\bibitemsep}\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.1\baselineskip plus .05\baselineskip minus .05\baselineskip}
\newlength{\bibparskip}\setlength{\bibparskip}{0pt}
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%
  \oldthebibliography{#1}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\bibitemsep}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibparskip}%
}

% biblatex-chicago: set formatting defaults and pass options
\PassOptionsToPackage%
    {isbn=false, autolang=other, footmarkoff, backend=biber}%
    {biblatex-chicago}
\if@authordateformat
    \PassOptionsToPackage{authordate}{biblatex-chicago}
\fi

% biblatex-chicago: adjustments to \printbibliography formatting
\if@appendbibformat
    \AtEndPreamble{%
        \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}%
            {%
                \if@authordateformat
                    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
                        bibliography = {References}}
                \else
                    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
                        references = {Bibliography}}
                \fi
                \renewcommand{\bibsetup}{%
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{\tf@topsecname}{\bibname}
                    \vspace{\dimexpr -2\tf@singlelineskip +1\baselineskip \relax}%
                    \singlespacing%
                    \def\tf@adjaftersec{\dimexpr \tf@singlelineskip -\p@ \relax}}
                \renewcommand{\bibitemsep}{1\baselineskip}
                \renewcommand{\bibhang}{0.5in}
            }{}}
\fi


% Endnotes: support and formatting

\if@endnotesformat

    \RequirePackage{endnotes, xparse}

    % Changes footnote marker type and formatting
    \tf@setfnpunct{}
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

    \PassOptionsToPackage{notetype=endonly}{biblatex-chicago}
    
    \AtEndPreamble{%
        % Make endnotes use of "_" not a special character when in text mode
        \appto{\enoteheading}{%
            \catcode`_=12
            \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
            \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
            \mathcode`_="8000}
```

And this is the template I copy from. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/turabian-formatted-thesis-slash-dissertation/qkyvdqrsgmnf

Thanks

Comment: `biblatex` uses different lengths that you can change: `\bibitemsep`, and `\bibnamesep`, `\bibinitsep`, which set the space between entries generally, different names, and different letter groups. You can use `\setlength` to change them as desired -- e.g., `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{2\baselineskip}`. If that doesn´t work, a full, but minimal file showing the problem will likely be needed.

Comment: To me it looks as though the screenshot is not of the bibliography produced by `biblatex` via `\printbibliography`, but of the footnotes produced by various citation commands. such `biblatex` has little control over the formatting of those footnotes, they are mostly controlled by your document class (and possibly a few other packages). Please show us a small example document that reproduces your current setup with as little code as possible.

Comment: Thanks @jon and @moewe! Unfortunately, I've tried `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1\baselineskip}` and it doesn't change. I just put all my code at the top, and it's a little bit long LOL, so I also put the template I copy from. Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you please tell us whether you want to change the space between the in-text references (the citation) or whether you want to change the space in the bibliography at the end (`\printbibliography`). It would also help if you could tell us whether you want to make the space smaller or bigger.

Comment: @moewe No, the space of in-text is okay for me. I want to change the space between each reference(space between 17&18, 18&19...and so on), and I want to make the space smaller. Seems like the current space is double space, and I want to change to single space.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the spacing between footnotes, you can set the `\footnotesep` length to a different value. This is best done in the document preamble (in your `.tex` file, between declaring the document class at the start and `\begin{document}`). There is no need to modify the `turabian-formatting.sty` file nor make any changes to the setup of `biblatex`.

In setting `\footnotesep`, it is possible to dynamically set the value based on its existing value minus the value of a single line skip for footnotes (effectively removing the spacing between footnotes). More so, the spacing after the footnote rule also needs to be set. To make these changes, place the following code in the preamble of your `.tex` file:

```
\makeatletter
    \newlength\new@footnotesep
    \setlength\new@footnotesep{\dimexpr\footnotesep - \tf@fnsinglelineskip\relax}
    \setlength\footnotesep{\new@footnotesep}

    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
        \kern-3\p@
        \hrule \@width 2in height 0.4\p@
        \kern4\p@}
\makeatother
```

Hope this helps... and [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! But the thing that I want to change is the `reference` not `footnote`.  (Yes, because it was written in Turabian format, so different from MLA or others, each reference would be written again under that page.)

Comment: No problem. I think there might be some confusion. A Turabian-formatted citation of a work, as you mentioned, can be placed at the bottom of the page in which a reference to it is made -- repeating the citation each time it is referenced. It does this, however, by placing the citation in a footnote. The image you shared in your question shows as much; and the spacing between each caused by the formatting of footnotes (and not the citations themselves). The answer changes the footnotes and, thus, the spacing between the references at the bottom of each page.

Comment: @Megan Your template has citations in footnotes. The screenshot you have shown is most likely of those citations in footnotes, so when you ask about changing the space, people will assume you talk about those footnote citations. This is especially true sine you were told about `\bibitemsep` and friends (which change the space in the bibliography/references produces by `\printbibliography`), but you said that those did not do what you wanted. I suggest you create a small example document and a screenshot that shows *exactly* what you want to change in which way.